# Big O notation for three nested for loops with if else statements

Tags: big-o

Here is the algorithm:

```
for j= 1 to m do   
 //assign values 
end for

for t = 1 to T do  
  for j = 1 to m do
      if t < T then
        for d = 1 to t do
          // perform some operation
        end for
      else
        for d = 1 to t do
          // Different operations
        end for  
  end for

 for j = 1 to m do  
  for i = 1 to m
     // doing some operations  
  end for 
 end for

 end for
```

I am calculating Big O notation for the above loops. My understanding says that big O notation would be O(Tm(T+m)). Could someone shed some light whether its right or wrong?